# google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded

Tags: publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub, google-publisher-tag

google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded
using python 3.7 ,google-cloud-pubsub ==1.1.0 publishing data on topic. In my local machine it's working perfectly fine and able to publish data on that topic and also able to pull data from that topic through subscriber.
    but don't understand it's not working when i deploy the code on server and it's failing with **INLINE ERROR** however when i explicitly call the publisher method on server it's publishing fine over server box also.code which is failing at below line while publishing:

```
future = publisher.publish(topic_path, data=data)

**ERROR:2020-02-20 14:24:42,714 ERROR Failed to publish 1 messages.**
Trackback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 57, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 729, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
        details = "Deadline Exceeded"
        debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1582208682.711481693","description":"Deadline Exceeded","file":"src/core/ext/filters/deadline/deadline_filter.cc","file_line":69,"grpc_status":14}"
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/timeout.py", line 214, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 Deadline Exceeded
```

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/publisher/_batch/thread.py", line 219, in _commit
    response = self._client.api.publish(self._topic, self._messages)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/gapic/publisher_client.py", line 498, in publish
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 143, in **call**
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 286, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 206, in retry_target
    last_exc,
  File "", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.RetryError: Deadline of 60.0s exceeded while calling functools.partial(.error_remapped_callable at 0x7f67d064e950>

Comment: This looks like a permission or network issue. Where did you deploy it to? Does the server you deployed to have the right network or IAM setting?

Comment: I posted a possible solution below, could you post a little bit more of your code, so I can acutally see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

You should try to chunk your data in reasonable sized chunks (max_messages) and don't forget to add a done callback.

```
# Loop over json containing records/rows
for idx, row in enumerate(rows_json):
    publish_json(row, idx, rowmax=len(rows_json), topic_name)

# Publish messages asynchronous 
def publish_json(msg, rowcount, rowmax, topic_project_id, topic_name):
    batch_settings = pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings(max_messages=100)
    publisher = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(batch_settings)
    topic_path = publisher.topic_path(topic_project_id, topic_name)
    future = publisher.publish(
        topic_path, bytes(json.dumps(msg).encode('utf-8')))
    future.add_done_callback(
        lambda x: logging.info(
            'Published msg with ID {} ({}/{} rows).'.format(
                future.result(), rowcount, rowmax))
    )
```